# html footer tag in wordpress showing a tag href separately in [ ] & sidebar is not coming

Tags: html, wordpress

here http://smallbusinessauthority.com.au/blog/, href is shown in "[ ]" for author meta next to the post date. Code is using footer html tag and if i removed the footer tag,, then it is working fine.

```
<footer class="entry-meta">
                        <span class="by-author">By <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="http://smallbusinessauthority.com.au/author/admin/" title="View all posts by admin" rel="author">admin</a></span></span> on <a href="http://smallbusinessauthority.com.au/objectives-management-the-key-to-success-for-the-largest-to-the-smallest-businesses-and-what-the-solution-providers-dont-tell-you/" title="8:59 am" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="2013-07-29T08:59:20+00:00">July 29, 2013</time></a>.                    </footer>
```

Even sidebar is not shown on the this blog page. Every settings is correct for sidebar and even it is caled properly in the file.

code in the template file is:
    "  style="margin-left:30px;">
        
        
            
        
        
        
            
            
            
            
            
                " title="" rel="bookmark">

```
    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
            <?php //twentytwelve_entry_meta(); ?>
        <?php else : ?>
            <?php twentytwelve_entry_meta(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php elseif ( is_single() ) : ?>
    <div class="entry-content" style="padding-bottom:20px; padding-top:0px;">
        <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content" style="padding-bottom:20px; padding-top:0px;">
        <?php echo substr(get_the_content(), 0 , 300). "...."; //the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
        <a href="<?php echo the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>
</article><!-- #post -->
```

Comment: Post the code for the full page so we can see what template tags you're using.

Comment: I put the code in question

Comment: You're echoing the_permalink() -- that function already prints out the link. You would only need to echo it if you were using get_the_permalink(). http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink

Comment: I made the changes but stillthe same thing

Comment: <footer class="entry-meta">
                      <span class="by-author">By <span class="author vcard"><a rel="author" title="View all posts by admin" href="http://smallbusinessauthority.com.au/author/admin/" class="url fn n">admin</a></span></span> on <a rel="bookmark" title="7:45 am" href="http://smallbusinessauthority.com.au/business-start-up-success-checklist-and-score/"><time datetime="2013-07-31T07:45:27+00:00" class="entry-date">July 31, 2013</time></a>.              </footer> if i made footer to footer1 then it is coming correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are describing is because of these lines of code in your CSS:

```
footer a[rel=bookmark]:link:after,
footer a[rel=bookmark]:visited:after {
    content: " [" attr(href) "] "; /* Show URLs */
}
```

(http://smallbusinessauthority.com.au/wp-content/themes/SBA/style.css?ver=3.5.1).

They place the `[` and `]` around your footer.
You can override that in your own CSS class or remove it if you can.
That basically wraps your `href` attribute in `[]` and place that as content of your link.

See http://www.quirksmode.org/css/content.html for more explanation.

Comment: Forgot about tone thing, sidebar is also not coming what is the issue behind that

Comment: What sidebar do you mean? The one where it says : 'Employment
Management
Marketing – Content Marketing
Productivity'?

Comment: correct view is like http://screencast.com/t/DnlIIDEt but no idea how it got effected

Comment: if you set `.site-content { width:72%; }` it should work. It is now set to `auto` which moves your sidebar to the bottom.